# (Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal) not found in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I need to install some package of python (numpy,pandas ..)in vs code.
for this action I need to Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal but I don't found this command on command bar

Comment: What do you mean by "command bar"? Do you mean the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)?

Comment: yes sorry, command palette

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install these python packages you don't need to open vscode's terminal you can just open the command console or a powershell and type :

```
pip install numpy
```

for example

And if you want the vscode terminal:
[image]

Normally it should be here you need to click Terminal > New Terminal

Comment: While true, this doesn't really address the problem of the option not being found in VSCode

Comment: Yes you are right I didnt understand the question at first but i edited my answer, thanks @OneCricketeer

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.20.1).                                                                                                                 but yet in vscode numpy doesn't find

Comment: How many versions of python have you installed? I think you have 2 versions and when you pip install it goes to python3.8 but when you try importing it on vscode you have another version of python selected. There is a solution for this you create a python virtual environment and you activate it and install all your libraries in it and chose the venv when selecting an interpreter in vscode.
Here is a link on how to create venv in python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can not find this:

[image]

Could you try to create it with the shortcut of **Ctrl+Shift+`** Or click the plus button in the terminal?

[image]

And you can switch to the anaconda environment to reuse the packages, you can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) for more details.